# How to send an email with password details in JSF

Tags: java, security, email

Suppose a user forgot his password and he wants to know his password. He has to provide an answer for his security question. After providing the correct answer, I want to send an email with password details to the user's email address.

So, what mail configurations should I do in jsf so that it interacts with many email addresses of respective users?

Comment: this has nothing to do with JSF

Comment: i am using jsf , so how can i do it using managed bean. please help

Answer (score 0):

So, what's really your question here?

- How do I mail using JSF?
- What is a safe solution to provide the user with a new login?

I think it's best for you to start looking into some solutions as [Javamail API - FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html).
There are several ways to set up a connection to be able to send mails.

Personally, I would not send an email containing passwords. This is just asking for trouble.
How about sending a link with a location like **resetpassword.xhtml?hash=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx** to redirect the user to a form in which he can set a new password? This hash would need to be generated just for this user, a random hash would do.
When he submits the form using the correct username/email and the correct hash, the new password can be submitted.